# tkinter not binding all the specified labels?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I was trying to create a Tkinter application in which when you click and drag the mouse, it will print the initial and final position of the mouse pointer.

There is a nested list containing labels whom I want to bind. I first bind the left click on each label, then when the label is left-clicked I bind its release. And when the left click is released, it prints the initial and the final position of the mouse pointer relative to the label.

So here is the code

```
from  tkinter import *

class game(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.llist = [[0]*4]*4
        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(4):
                self.llist[i][j] = Label(self,bd = 1, relief = 'ridge',height = 4, width = 8)
                self.llist[i][j].grid(row = i, column = j)
                self.llist[i][j].bind('<Button-1>',lambda event, r = i, c = j: self.click(event,r,c))

    def click(self,event,r,c):
        a,b = event.x,event.y
        self.llist[r][c].bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',lambda event: self.release(event,a,b))

    def release(self,event,a,b):
        print(a,b,event.x,event.y)

r = Tk()
r.geometry('300x300')

f = game(r)
f.pack()

r.mainloop()
```

But the problem is that only the last 4 labels work!

The problem is with the second binding. When I test only the first binding, all the labels work!

Please Help!!!

Comment: That doesn't help @stovfl I have already declared local variables in lambda and that's not making any difference.

Comment: But why down vote???

Comment: Read up on [Why is voting important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is caused by the line:

```
self.llist = [[0]*4]*4
```

It created list of 4 lists that reference to the same list, i.e. `self.llist[r][c]` reference to the same `self.llist[0][c]`.

Change it to `self.llist = [[0]*4 for _ in range(4)]`.

Comment: Thank You so much